# Having Trouble with Async Task and Flow of Program

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I am currently designing an app that lets users read news articles and its necessary to get information from the internet in order to populate a list and display it to the user. I've done all the parsing work and the correct information for the articles is being returned okay. I have one main activity in my app with fragments and these are setup with a view pager. So I have three tabs that the user can switch between. This looks similar to the Zedge app currently on the market. Since I have separate fragments where is a wise place to put the Async task in my app?

I was going to put it in the main activity's onCreate method but since async tasks run in the background at the same time with the UI thread, things are getting setup blank with nothing in them since the async task is not done yet. It seems by the time my asyc task is to the postExecute method, the UI setup is either done or almost done and the variable (an arraylist) that is supposed to have the return from the async task is empty. And I'm guessing I can't just assign the returned onPostExecute value to a static variable since I have no idea when the async task will be done in relation to the UI thread?

I also had another idea of putting methods for updating the fragments UI in their classes and having the onPostExecute call them to modify things(ie. repopulate UI elements). I understand that it's not a good idea to have the UI thread explicitly wait, so I'm trying to avoid this. Is my async task at least okay? Hopefully everything I said didn't sound like a bunch of jumble. If someone could help me understand how to load my app's information I would certainly appreciate it!

```
private class GetArticlesFromRSS extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Article>>
{

    ArrayList<Article> retArtList = new ArrayList<Article>();
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Article> doInBackground(Void... v)
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        artReaderObj = new ArticleRSSReader(urlArticles);

        try
        {
            artReaderObj.fetchXML();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {

            task1.cancel(true);

        }

        while (artReaderObj.parsingComplete)
            ;
        retArtList.addAll(artReaderObj.getArticles());


        return retArtList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Article> result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        articlesReturned = result;


        if (MainActivity.articlesReturned.size() > 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error, Check Network Connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The only thing I didn't quite get... what is your question? How to have your UI not show blank information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one simple solution to overcome and return your data in any class / activity / fragment.

You have write a custom listener in asynctask class (GetArticlesFromRSS in your case) and call listener in onPostExecute method.

example of listener

```
    public interface OnAsyncResult {  
        public abstract void onResultSuccess(ArrayList<Article> result);  
        public abstract void onResultFail(int resultCode, String errorMessage);  
   }
```

create object on OnAsyncResult in your "GetArticlesFromRSS.java"
lets say

```
OnAsyncResult onAsyncResult = null;

setOnAsyncResult(OnAsyncResult callBack)
{
  this.onAsyncResult = callback;
}
```

then in your post execute method you can use this listener as below

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Article> result)
{
    dialog.dismiss();
    articlesReturned = result;


    if (MainActivity.articlesReturned.size() > 0){
        if(onAsyncResult!=null)
            onAsyncResult.onResultSuccess(result);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        if(onAsyncResult!=null)
            onAsyncResult.onResultFail(1, "Error, Check Network Connection.");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error, Check Network Connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

This will solve your purpose.

Comment: This definitely sounds like what I'm looking for and need. I knew that there had to be some kind of design to accomplish what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I will report back.

Comment: Now I'm fully realizing what your solution does. I like this a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be better to use a service in this case. When the UI needs update can bind the service and get the information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make the UI thread wait...

The postExecute runs on the UI thread, so you can set your ui elements from that method.  You should define how to set them in your Acivity / Fragments, and then have the post execute call these methods with the information to update the UI.

Also, inflating a view takes like fractions of a second.  You can launch the async tasks after inflation to be sure the UI elements are there.  Or you could do something more complicated like caching the result if you NEED to launch the async before inflation (and its possible for it to return before the app is done).