# updating UI thread while in asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

as the title states, im trying to update something in my UI thread while running an asynctask.. i've read quite a bit on asynctask and it seems i should be able to change a
variable from the onPostExecute() method. obviously this is not the case.

Here is my sample code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thingsThatNeedToBeUpdated); 
Login login = new Login();
login.execute(userName, password);
```

and here the the login class

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>{
    public String doInBackground(String... params){
       logMeIn(params[0], params[1]);
    }
    public void onPostExecute(String update){
       tv.setText(result); //this is not working!!
    }
```

whats actually happening is tv is underlined red and eclipse says i need to create a local variable.. but i thought the onPostExecute is ran from the UI thread? confused :?
im trying to do what i found at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) website. I'm not entirly sure what i'm doing and i would love a point in the right direction! thanks in advance.

Comment: i updated the question to further identify the problem

Comment: Login is in a Different .java class?

Comment: Where are you instantiating tv? Because findViewById() will return null in your activesync surely?

Comment: To be honest to point you towards the right direction you should read a good Java Book, seems like you have no idea of variables scope and that's basic before moving forward in Android...

Comment: It runs on the UI thread, but those UI elements you are trying to access are defined in another class or the references to them are local variables,

Comment: Login is your inner class or outer?

Comment: ok, so i can't run this from a different .java class? my understanding of scope is fine, it's my lack of understanding of nested classes that seems to be the trouble. thank you all.

Comment: Ahhhh, you have it in a nested class. Could of helped us to know that in the question. :p

Comment: Check this post for your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234924/having-trouble-with-async-task-and-flow-of-program/22235712#22235712

Comment: thank you, i resolved this and accepted the answer i used to fix this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thingsThatNeedToBeUpdated);
```

is obviously declared either

1. Outside of a method -which would result in `tv` being `null` or
2. In a method that isn't part of the `AsyncTask`- which would mean the
   task doesn't have access to it

You should define it as a member variable (outside of a method)

```
TextView tv;
```

then initialize it inside of a method

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thingsThatNeedToBeUpdated);
```

This will give your task access to it as well as the rest of your class.

If your `AsyncTask` is a separate file than your `Activity` then you will want to [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) on using an `interface` and create a callback to update the `TextView` in your `Activity`.

Comment: This helped a lot. My AsyncTask was in its own .java file, so my problem was a scope issue. I solved this by passing my textView into a constructor for my AsyncTask class. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To bring your `TextView` instance into scope, pass your tv variable into your `Login` instance constructor and add the constructor and variable in as below.

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>{

    private TextView tv;

    public Login(TextView tv){
       this.tv = tv;
    }
    public String doInBackground(String... params){
       logMeIn(params[0], params[1]);
    }
    public void onPostExecute(String update){
       tv.setText(result); //this should work
    }
}
```

You have to pass the variable to this instance, otherwise it is out of scope. You won't be able to access it unless you declare and instantiate a new variable within the `Login` class.

Answer (score 0):

Place `TextView tv;` into the scope of the class and outside of the function. Leave `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thingsThatNeedToBeUpdated);` where it is. You should then be able to access `tv` from `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the TextView variable tv is defined in another class that does not have Login as an inner class. If Login is an inner class of the class containing the variable tv, it should be able to see the variable tv.

An easy way to solve this would be to make your AsyncTask an inner class of your main class.